# Gparted - cannot change size of SSD

Tags: ssd, gparted, partitioning

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my Laptop on a SSD and a Windows 7 on a HDD.
I'd like to install Kubuntu parallel to Ubuntu on the SSD.

Now when trying to install Kubuntu it doesn't show me the SSD in the menu when asking where I'd like to install.
When using the KDE partition manager of Kubuntu's live version, are 90% of the options grayed out!

I also can't change the size of the SSD on Ubuntu with GParted - I cant move this arrow on the right hand side and the numbers of the filesize jump back to their original value when trying to change!

I can't even change the size of the SSD on Windows, the resize option is grayed out!

Sincerely,
Flap

Edit: There is a key-symbol on the partioning list of gparted (it says /dev/sda1 *KEYSYMBOL*, /dev/sda2 *KEYSYMBOL* and /dev/sda3 *KEYSYMBOL*.

Comment: Have you unmounted the disk? You unmounted by right-clicking and pressing Unmount. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EoiwB.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EoiwB.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40947/discussion-on-question-by-flap-gparted-cannot-change-size-of-ssd).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is not a forum, but a Q&A site. Rather than putting your solution in the question, please edit it out and put it in the answer space. You can then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
I was able to split the SSD with a live usb stick with Kubuntu on it. 
The default partion manager didnt work, but I installed gparted on the live stick and could do what Ubuntu and Windows refused to do for me.

No idea why the other ways didnt work, but now I know that i can install programs in live-stick session!
Thanks for your great help!

Comment: You wee utilizing the disk that you were trying to change the partition size of. Thus why booting off of the live cd allowed you to change partition size because your ssd was not in use.